# What to do when preloading assets in jQuery/JavaScript fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, preloader

### Description of Issue:

Let's say I have a site making gratuitous use of graphics and audio. I want to frontload all these assets, showing a 'preload' screen (i.e. a DIV that will fade out) before the actual site becomes usable.

The problem I'm encountering is that, frequently, a file will fail to load (this appears to happen most often in Chrome -- possibly related to the number of concurrent connections?). Naturally, this prevents the site from loading (i.e. `loadSite()` is never triggered). What should I be doing in that case? Is there a way to re-try loading the file? Should I just load the site anyway after *X* amount of time? What is the typical fallback solution here? And what would cause my assets to fail loading about a quarter of the time anyway?

An example of the preloader is provided below. Feel free to critique it; I'd love to see a better solution for JavaScript preloading, if it's out there. Any improvement in efficiency or reliability would be most welcome.

### Code:

```
var Images = {
    1:  'img/one.png',
    2:  'img/two.jpg',
    3:  'img/three.gif',
    4:  'img/four.png',
    5:  'img/five.jpg'
}
var Sounds = { 
    1:  'snd/one.ogg',
    2:  'snd/two.mp3',
    3:  'snd/three.wav',
    4:  'snd/four.ogg',
    5:  'snd/five.mp3'
}
var filesToLoad = Object.keys(Images).length + Object.keys(Sounds).length,
    filesLoaded = 0;

function preloadImages() {
    for (var key in Images) {
        if (Images.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            loadImage(Images[key]);
        }
    }
}
function loadImage(uri) {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = isFileLoaded;
    img.src = uri;
}

function preloadSounds() {
    for (var key in Sounds) {
        if (Sounds.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            loadSound(Sounds[key]);
        }
    }
}

function loadSound(uri) {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', isFileLoaded, false);
    audio.src = uri;
}

function isFileLoaded() {
    filesLoaded++;
    alert(filesLoaded + ' of ' + filesToLoad + ' assets loaded'); //Debug
    if (filesLoaded >= filesToLoad) {
        loadSite();
    }
}

function loadSite() {
    //Load the site here
}

preloadImages();
preloadSounds();
```

Comment: Add `onerror` handlers and if it will be critical to load all add alert/tooltip with message "Content not loaded, refresh the page".

Comment: Have you considered `jQuery`'s `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: @AndyM Can you elaborate?  Not at all sure what you're implying.

Comment: @Pinal I was hoping for something a little more elegant than telling the user to refresh the page. :-) Seems more like a last resort.

Comment: jQuery comes with a built in wrapper function, that you put everything else in. This waits until the document is loaded to fire. That said, I've looked into it and don't see anything about error handling. What about loading everything via Ajax? That DOES have error handling.

Comment: @AndyM Let's say I switch to AJAX and using its error handling a file fails to load. What do you do then? This is my original question. Do you attempt to reload the file? Do you tell the user about it and continue onward with a broken site? What is the proper protocol? What is best practice?

Comment: What I would do is place fullscreen cover over the site that says Loading and set jQuery to hide it when the page is loaded. Then I'd have a separate loop that checks to see if the cover is still visible after a set time, and if it is, changes the word Loading to an error message. However, that is personal rather than best practice. I'm not sure there really IS a best practice, because it shouldn't occur often, if ever. It's an underlying cause vs a bandaid question. Having a first aid kit is good (to handle errors), but if you keep having to use it, you need to address why that is.

Comment: Submit that as an answer. :-)